# Make 1 = 0 and 0 = 1 in javascript

Tags: javascript

Slightly abstract question this, but I'd be interested to know a more succinct way of writing:

```
if( i.css('opacity') == 1 ) 
    o = 0; 
else 
    o = 1;
```

So if `something` == 1, make `another` = 0 and if `something` == 0 make `another` = 1

There must be some sort of multiplication I can do on `something` to achieve this? My maths sucks.

Comment: `var another = something === 1 ? 0 : 1;`?

Comment: Booleans coerce to numbers 1 for true, and 0 for false. So just do a negated numeric conversion of your boolean result. `o = +!(i.css.('opacity') == 1)`

Comment: an inline if can do that.

Comment: you are doing exactly what is needed..why do want a multiplication process?

Comment: You weren't really trying to make 1 = 0 and 0 = 1 because that's never possible to be done.

Comment: According to your current logic, any value less than `1` should give an `o=1` result. Is that what you intend? So `0`, `.01` and `.99` will all get `1`?

Answer (score 7):

Use the [ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator)

```
o = (i.css('opacity') == 1) ? 0 : 1;
```

Comment: why on earth didn't i think of that? embarrassing. i'm tired. thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4):

`+!0` makes 1, `+!1` makes 0. You can just type `o = +!i.css('opacity')`.

Welcome to the wacky world of JavaScript!

Comment: »Welcome to the wacky world of JavaScript!« yes, it is :]

Comment: @ThomasJunk, although I had to try it and it works in C and C++ as well - so that's a slight misattribution of silliness in my part.

Comment: sshh... Do not tell anybody else ;-)

Answer (score 2):

```
o = !i.css('opacity');
```

Will for the most part have the same effect, even if it's not `1` or `0` but a boolean. Assumes `opacity` is either `1` or `0`.

Answer (score 1):

A short solution is:

```
o=~~!(i.css('opacity'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try absolute value. 0 - 1 = -1 and 1 - 1 = 0. The absolute value function makes -1 into 1.

```
Math.abs(o - 1);
```